# How to merge two arrays by taking over only values from the second array that has the same keys as the first one?

Tags: php, arrays, filter, array-merge, array-key

I'd like to merge two arrays with each other:

```
$filtered = array(1 => 'a', 3 => 'c');
$changed = array(2 => 'b*', 3 => 'c*');
```

Whereas the merge should include all elements of `$filtered` and all those elements of `$changed` that have a corresponding key in `$filtered`:

```
$merged = array(1 => 'a', 3 => 'c*');
```

`array_merge($filtered, $changed)` would add the additional keys of `$changed` into `$filtered` as well. So it does not really fit.

I know that I can use `$keys = array_intersect_key($filtered, $changed)` to get the keys that exist in both arrays which is already half of the work.

However I'm wondering if there is any (native) function that can reduce the `$changed` array into an array with the `$keys` specified by `array_intersect_key`? I know I can use `array_filter` with a callback function and check against `$keys` therein, but there is probably some other purely native function to extract only those elements from an array of which the keys can be specified?

I'm asking because the native functions are often much faster than `array_filter` with a callback.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should do it, if I'm understanding your logic correctly:

```
array_intersect_key($changed, $filtered) + $filtered
```

---

Implementation:

```
$filtered = array(1 => 'a', 3 => 'c');
$changed = array(2 => 'b*', 3 => 'c*');
$expected = array(1 => 'a', 3 => 'c*');    
$actual = array_key_merge_deceze($filtered, $changed);

var_dump($expected, $actual);

function array_key_merge_deceze($filtered, $changed) {
    $merged = array_intersect_key($changed, $filtered) + $filtered;
    ksort($merged);
    return $merged;
}
```

Output:

```
Expected:
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "c*"
}

Actual:
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "c*"
}
```

Comment: Union against the intersection. But union will add keys of `$filtered` as well AFAIK. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Jup. I just tested it, my fault ;). It works pretty well, only the order of keys changes, but that's no problem as I have them as a numerical index, so ksort does the job. Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @deceze `array_intersect_key($changed, $filtered) + $filtered` Strange. I never seen that before. No idea what's happens here, but it works! What is the job for `+ $filtered`

Comment: @The `array_intersect_key($changed, $filtered)` takes all values from `$changed` which have a key in `$filtered`, i.e. it produces a subset of `$filtered` with the values from `$changed`. `+ $filtered` then adds the rest of the values from `$filtered` back into the result, i.e. it fills the subset back up to have all the keys in `$filtered`.

Comment: You may want to place a return `$changed` when `$filtered` is empty depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the second array ($b) to be the pattern that indicates that if there is only the key there, then you could also try this

```
$new_array =  array_intersect_key( $filtered, $changed ) + $changed;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your keys are non-numeric (which yours are not, so this is not a solution to your exact question), then you can use this technique:

```
$filtered = array('a' => 'a', 'c' => 'c');
$changed = array('b' => 'b*', 'c' => 'c*');

$merged = array_slice(array_merge($filtered, $changed), 0, count($filtered));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => a
    [c] => c*
)
```

This works because for non-numeric keys, `array_merge` overwrites values for existing keys, and appends the keys in `$changed` to the end of the new array. So we can simply discard any keys from the end of the merged array more than the count of the original array.

Since this applies to the same question but with different key types I thought I'd provide it.

If you use this with numeric keys then the result is simply the original array (`$filtered` in this case) with re-indexed keys (IE as if you used `array_values`).